# Web hosting for Mono?

Tags: mono, web-hosting

I see a lot of linux-based PHP hosting solutions in the $5/month range. Does anybody know of one in that range that uses/can use Mono? I've written some C# code I want to use, but want to avoid ASP.NET.

Comment: MonoDevelop is an IDE, not a platform. Are you looking for **mono** hosting?

Comment: Question is incorrect. There are no hosting solutions for IDE. What you are looking for is probably an ASP.NET hosting.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I have some C# code I want to use, but want to avoid ASP.NET.

Comment: Then you should search for `Mono`, not `Monodevelop`.

Comment: See also this sister question on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/76416/where-are-you-going-for-mono-hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mono Project Web Hosting](http://www.ubiquityhosting.com/web-hosting/service/mono) should do:

> The Mono Project (a.k.a. mod_mono) is an open-source .NET Framework emulation tool for Linux sponsored by Novell. Through Mono, we have assembled a simple and easy-to-use web hosting platform which bridges the gap which previously existed between Windows and Linux hosting providers. What was once properietary Microsoft technology has been made available to the open-source developer community, and supplied right here with our premium Linux hosting service.

Comment: Thanks. Once I stopped searching for "MonoDevelop hosting" I found this too :)

Comment: The exact place where it mentions mono is here, was hard to find from the initial homepage: https://www.ubiquityhosting.com/joomla-hosting

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why no one said this. But if you are developing a website using mono and c#, you are using asp.net... just a linux implementation of it.

Comment: You can use mono and host the app on a unix system, instead of windows server. You can run it with nginx or apache for example. It isn't just an implementation , gives you an alternative to windows server

Comment: This should *not* be downvoted.  @Renato is exactly right, and the OP is very confused: "I have some C# code I want to use, but want to avoid ASP.NET".  Ummm... it's going to take a lot more than Mono to accomplish that goal, and Mono won't actually move him any closer to the goal.  If he had said "...but I want to avoid IIS" or "...but I want to avoid Windows", then his question might have made sense.  To use C# but not ASP.NET probably means writing your own web framework from the ground up using `TcpClient` or something like that.

Comment: He may be using ServiceStack.NET that IMHO is much nicer for modern REST services than ASP.NET that tends to just get in the way.

Answer (score 2):

I've found another free host
http://www.heliohost.org/

It [explicitly states](http://www.heliohost.org/home/features/languages/aspnet) that it uses mono.